# Load mapping file in google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm using the new Google Play console version and I'm not able to find how to load a mapping file in case of obfuscated APK. I looked at every menu, I looked at the docs, can someone explain how to load the file with the new interface?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Click on "Releases Overview" in the left panel.
2. In the "Latest Releases" section, click on the version for which you want to upload your mapping file
3. In the "App Bundles and APKs" section, you would see a row with your added App Bundle or APK.
4. Click on the 3 dots menu on it's right end. This would open a menu with an option to "Upload ReTrace mapping file (.txt or .map)"

[image]

Comment: Oh my god Google, it was really hidden, why? :( Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

New instructions are listed here, if anyone else is still looking: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the mapping.txt file now is uploading automatically in Google Play. At least that has been my case.

I have followed these steps, and I have verified that the mapping.txt file was already uploaded.

Comment: this is because they probably speak about APK and you about AAB.
"This step is only required for developers using APKs. If you’re using an app bundle and Android Gradle plugin
version 4.1 or later, then there's nothing you need to do."